# Copied a let's encrypt certificate from one server to another, how to auto renew?

Tags: ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I have just copied a SSL certificate (generated via let's encrypt certbot) from one server (A) to another (B). So, I have created a custom directory in my new server, let's say `/home/my-certificate/`, and copied the `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` from (A) to (B). Everything works, the server is alive, the certificate are OK. Now I want to enable auto-renew on the new server (B). How can I do that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two good options stand out

1. Copy the Let's Encrypt certbot metadata from A to B as well, then install and continue to use certbot to renew as usual. This metadata is kept in /etc/letsencrypt/ and it tracks how your certificate was issued, from which certbot will conclude how it should renew it.

OR

2. Install certbot and perform a fresh certificate request on B, any time between now and when the existing certificate would expire. Assuming the certificate is for the *exact same* list of FQDNs this will only count against the per-certificate limit of 5 such requests per week, which is fine unless you're going to do this transition every day or you keep screwing it up and having to try again.

Comment: Ok thank you! Option 2 seems better (cleaner) right? In option 1, you spoke about "metadata". Did you mean every subdirectories in that directory?

Comment: If the certificate in question is the only one on server A then yes, everything. If server A also had other certificates that aren't to be moved to server B, you will need to be more careful in what gets moved but the naming system is pretty transparent if you look in there.

Comment: I think Certbot should make this easier. Moving to a different server is very common and should be easy. All the required files should be in one directory. That directory should be the same for all distros. Because migrations are often chaotic enough already, people pulling out their hair, babies crying, that's not a time when you want to be tweaking configuration options with fingers crossed.

Comment: Also, as an idea I want to try by myself: the main server could run a post-process script to copy the certificate from one server to another using scp/sftp and run various commands via ssh in the condition the authorized_keys are properly set at the target server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy letsencrypt renewal config to the new server, and then modify nginx config to point to the new, custom location: `/home/my-certificate/`

I would suggest moving your certs to the exact same location on the new server, in this case, you can just copy and paste certs and config without any modification.

Here is the list of steps:

1. Archive certificates on the old servers
2. Move them to a new server
3. Extract to the correct location
4. Create symlinks
5. Redirect domain

Based on [this article](https://druss.co/2019/03/migrate-letsencrypt-certificates-certbot-to-new-server/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Druss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374353/2579739), a few more steps to be followed.

The solution provided will encounter problems when you try to renew the certificate.

To resolve this issue, a new certbot account should be registered, and conf file should be edited pointing to the new account. I followed the steps provided in this [link](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/couldnt-renew-because-of-missing-account/142707).